# Filter an Array through id and then mapping through a nested array inside

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, filter

I'm stuck since a while trying to access a nested array inside another array after filtering it by an id. To be clear, this is the mock data I have:

```
  bundleSets: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "bundle set 1",
                bundles: [
                    {
                        bundleTitle: "bundle 1",
                        content:[]
                    },
                    {
                        bundleTitle: "bundle 2",
                        content:[]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {   id:2,
                title: "bundle set 2",
                bundles: [
                    {bundleTitle: "ciaopao", content:[]}
                ]
            },
            {   id:3,
                title: "bundle set 3",
                bundles: [
                    {bundleTitle: "ciapo", content:[]}
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Now I need to filter each bundleSets by id, and then access the bundles array inside and mapping those elements. This is what I tried to do:

```
 const [key,setKey]=useState(1)
  const [bundles,setBundles]=useState([])
  
  
   


  useEffect(()=>{

    const filteredBundles = bundleSets && bundleSets.filter(bundleSet=>bundleSet.id==key).map(filteredBundles=>{
      return filteredBundles.bundles
    })

  setBundles(filteredBundles)

   

  },[key])
```

Now If I try mapping the new state I can see on the console.log a weird [Array(1)] instead of the usual [{}] and I can't render it to the page. Where am I getting wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array and the callback you're passing to the `map` method returns `filteredBundles.bundles` which is an array. So, you get an array of arrays. `filteredBundles` is a confusing name, btw.

Since you're looking up the bundle by id and the ids are unique in the `bundleSets` array, you can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the bundle set by id and then get the bundle array. You can return an empty array if `find` returns `undefined` (if the key is not found).

```js
const bundles = bundleSets?.find(set => set.id === key)?.bundles || []
```